# Italic (math) units with siunitx, kpfonts and lualatex

Tags: fonts, luatex, siunitx, kpfonts

This simple document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit\foo{\text{\ensuremath{F}}}

\begin{document}

\ensuremath{F} \si{\foo}

\end{document}
```

I compile it with `pdflatex` and it looks fine:

[image]

But with `lualatex`, the second F is upright:

[image]

Without `kpfonts` I get two similar-looking italic Fs. Is there some (easy) way to fix it with `kpfonts`?

Comment: Units are upright by decree of the BIPM.

Answer (score 1):

In v3, `siunitx` aims to create as far as possible the same math mode intermediate content as one would be hand for typesetting units: here `\mathrm{F}` with the standard settings. As a result, you are using effectively

```latex
\mathrm{\text{\ensuremath{F}}
```

which comes out upright. If you really want to get 'whatever', then you can disable the `unit-font-command`, for example

```latex
\makeatletter
\DeclareSIUnit[unit-font-command = \@firstofone]\foo{\text{\ensuremath{F}}}
\makeatother
```

(As noted in a comment, units should be typeset in the upright Roman font by convention: this is what the standard settings aim to do.)

Comment: That doesn't explain the difference between `pdflatex` and `lualatex`, does it? My intent is to manually define deprecated units like `\hartree` and `\bohr`, which may not be "officially" sanctioned, but are still commonly used and convenient. Using the "current" definitions, as output in the log, gives the engine-dependent behaviour above, but maybe there's something wrong in my installation (TeXLive 2022).

Comment: Engine- and font-dependent behavior. (I get an error when editing the above comment.)

Comment: @Jellby With LuaTeX, `unicode-math` is loaded, and the 'expected' behaviours change for the reference rendering of `\amthrm{\text{\ensuremath{F}}`.